# Perl specific transforms in python

Tags: python, regex, perl, transform, canonicalization

I need a Perl-specific code in Python.

Here is the Perl code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my $s = 'http://www.bergdorfgoodman.com/Ippolita-18k-Gold-Rock-Candy-Mini-Single-Square-Pendant-Necklace/prod108010011/p.prod#.U75MVqY-PtS';

$s =~ s/(.*\.com)\/[^\/]+(\/prod[^\_]*\/p\.prod).*/$1$2/si;


print $s ."\n";
```

I have handled the capturing part by $1 and $2, and I don't know how to do it in Python.

Output:

```
http://www.bergdorfgoodman.com/prod108010011/p.prod
```

Comment: `s{ \A( .+ [.] com) / [^/]+ (/ prod [^/]+  /p [.] prod) }{$1$2}six` ... Also, I do not know why you need `/s`. Do you really want the initial segment of the URL to possibly contain newlines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Python code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(.*\.com)\/[^\/]+(\/prod[^\_]*\/p\.prod).*', re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = u"http://www.bergdorfgoodman.com/Ippolita-18k-Gold-Rock-Candy-Mini-Single-Square-Pendant-Necklace/prod108010011/p.prod#.U75MVqY-PtS"
subst = ur"\1\2"
result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

In Python, you need to use `\1` instead of `$1` in the replacement string.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rW7zX5/1) and [code demo on IDEONE](http://ideone.com/5hdtPM)

Output:

```
http://www.bergdorfgoodman.com/prod108010011/p.prod
```

Comment: what does the "ur" and "u" mean?

Comment: `u` stands for Unicode, `r` just means we are using "raw" string where `\` does not need escaping. Very helpful when dealing with regular expressions.